# Mockito - Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

I know there are already at least two same questions asked, but I still can't figure out why I am getting the exception.
I need to unit test this method:

```
void setEyelet(final PdfWriter printPdf, final float posX, final float posY) {

    InputStream is = WithDefinitions.class.getResourceAsStream(RES_EYELET); //RES_EYELET is a pdf.
    PdfContentByte canvas = printPdf.getDirectContent();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
    PdfImportedPage page = printPdf.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    canvas.addTemplate(page, posX, posY);
    reader.close();
}
```

and verify that

```
canvas.addTemplate(page, posX, posY);
```

was called.

This method is nested in an another method:

```
void computeEyelets(final PdfWriter printPdf) {
        float lineLeft = borderLeft + EYELET_MARGIN;
        float lineRight = printPdfWidth - borderRight - EYELET_MARGIN - EYELET_SIZE;
        float lineTop = printPdfHeight - borderTop - EYELET_MARGIN - EYELET_SIZE;
        float lineBottom = borderBottom + EYELET_MARGIN;
        float eyeletDistMinH = 20;
        if (eyeletDistMinH != 0 || eyeletDistMinV != 0) {
         setEyelet(printPdf, lineLeft, lineBottom);
    }
```

And finally my unit test code:

```
public void computeEyeletsNoMirror() {
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = Mockito.mock(PdfWriter.class);
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = Mockito.mock(PdfContentByte.class);
    Mockito.when(pdfWriter.getDirectContent()).thenReturn(pdfContentByte);
    WithDefinitions withDefinitions = Mockito.mock(WithDefinitions.class);
    float lineLeft = BORDER_LEFT + EYELET_MARGIN;
    float lineBottom = BORDER_BOTTOM + EYELET_MARGIN;

    withDefinitions.setEyeletDistMinH(20);
    withDefinitions.setEyeletDistMinV(20);
    withDefinitions.setMirror(false);

    withDefinitions.computeEyelets(pdfWriter);

    Mockito.verify(pdfContentByte).addTemplate(
        Mockito.any(PdfImportedPage.class),
        Mockito.eq(lineLeft),
        Mockito.eq(lineBottom)
    );
```

I have no final methods, I use mocked pdf writer as a parameter. What do I need else to do to get the test passing?

**UPDATE**
Below is the exception message:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
 pdfContentByte.addTemplate(
  <any>,
  62.36221,
  62.36221
);
-> at ...tools.pdf.superimpose.WithDefinitionsTest.computeEyeletsNoMirror(WithDefinitionsTest.java:336)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

**UPDATE 2**
After replacing the mocked WithDefinitions object with the real instance I get the following output:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
pdfContentByte.addTemplate(
  <any>,
  62.36221,
  62.36221
);
-> at ...tools.pdf.superimpose.WithDefinitionsTest.computeEyeletsNoMirror(WithDefinitionsTest.java:336)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
pdfContentByte.addTemplate(
  null,
  48.18898,
  48.18898
);
-> at ...tools.pdf.superimpose.WithDefinitions.setEyelet(WithDefinitions.java:850)
```

Comment: Can you past the exception (with callstack) you get in your post?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636980/play-framework-java-mock-using-mockito-wanted-but-not-invoked-actually-there
<br>I have a similar issue, can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are mocking the object that you're testing. That makes no sense. You should create a real WithDefinitions object and call its real method to test it. If you mock it, by definition, all its methods are replaced by mock implementations that do nothing.

Replace

```
WithDefinitions withDefinitions = Mockito.mock(WithDefinitions.class);
```

by something like

```
WithDefinitions withDefinitions = new WithDefinitions();
```

Comment: Well, the error message is self explanatory. The test expects 62.36221 to be passed, and what is actually passed is 48.18898. So, either the code has a bug, or the test has a bug. Fix it.

Comment: @JBNizet shouldn't it be possible by using SPY? I am using spy the real method is ignored, but the verify fails.