# Wanted but not invoked. Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, jmockit

I tried solution given in [Exception : mockito wanted but not invoked, Actually there were zero interactions with this mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551926/exception-mockito-wanted-but-not-invoked-actually-there-were-zero-interaction) and this one too [Mockito - Wanted but not invoked: Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089601/mockito-wanted-but-not-invoked-actually-there-were-zero-interactions-with-th) but Still getting the same error. Am I missing something? 
Here is me implementation:-

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

class ClassOne {
    public void method(ClassTwo two) {
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    public ClassTwo(String value) {
    }
}

class MyClassTwo extends ClassTwo {
    public MyClassTwo(String value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

class ClassToBeTested {
    ClassOne classOne;

    public ClassToBeTested() {
        classOne = new ClassOne();
    }

    public void methodToBeTested() {
        ClassTwo event = new MyClassTwo("String");
        classOne.method(event);
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassToBeTestedTest {

    ClassToBeTested presenter;
    @Mock
    ClassOne classOne;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        presenter = new ClassToBeTested();
    }


    @Test
    public void testAbc() {
        presenter.methodToBeTested();
        ClassTwo event = new MyClassTwo("someString");
        verify(classOne).method(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass in the mocked class (or do something horrid with PowerMock).

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

class ClassWeWantToBeMocked {
    void methodToBeMocked() { }
}

class ClassToBeTested {
    ClassWeWantToBeMocked dependency;

    // Notice that the dependency is now passed in. 
    // This is commonly called Dependency Injection.
    public ClassToBeTested(ClassWeWantToBeMocked dependency){
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void methodToBeTested(){
        dependency.methodToBeMocked();
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassToBeTestedTest {

    ClassToBeTested presenter;

    @Mock
    ClassWeWantToBeMocked ourMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        // Notice how we now pass in the dependency (or in this case a mock)
        presenter=new ClassToBeTested(ourMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void myMockTest(){
        presenter.methodToBeTested();

        verify(ourMock).methodToBeMocked();
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed my class to have the instance of ClassOne in constructor  as you suggested, but still no luck. I also tried with different constructor which will call the new constructor after
`public ClassToBeTested(){
        this(new ClassOne());
    }`

Comment: It would help a lot if you supplied code that actually compiled and ran showing your issue. Updated with working example

Comment: That's exactly how my code is looked like, but still same problem. I have few more test classes in my package which is working fine but not this one. I guess something else is wrong :(